# Can’t boot into Ubuntu Studio 22.04 from USB drive

Tags: boot, busybox

My laptop is an HP, model: 15-G067CL. When I boot from my USB drive and select *Try or Install Ubuntu Studio*, it shows a screen with an HP logo in the middle and an Ubuntu logo below that. It appears as if the laptop is about to boot into Ubuntug, but then it gets stuck at a black screen with lines of code.

I took a photo of the boot screen and have attached it to this post.

[image]

Comment: 1. It could be a problem with the driver for the graphics card. What happens when you try with the option of the grub menu "Ubuntu Studio (safe graphics)"? 2. How did you create the USB boot drive (tool, method)? 3. Did you check with `sha256sum` that the download of the iso file was successful?

Comment: What is the size of the USB pendrive? You need more than 4 GB because the size of the iso file is approximately 4.2 GiB (4.4 GB).